# How to convert AngularJS form inside div to JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, forms

I have an AngularJS based web page with a few divs. One of the divs is used to hold different forms depending on user clicks in another div.

The ng-model naming scheme is as follows - ng-model="parameter.parameterName". 
Every field name is preceded by "parameter." in its ng-model.

In the form controller, if I use $scope.parameter and assign this to a var, the var remains undefined. However, if I do the same in a form which is directly inside a body, and has its own controller in the same file, $scope.parameter gives me a JSON object containing all values in the form.

Please help understand how to achieve this 2 way binding behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your controller isn't assigned to the view.

First things first: Check that your script file and angularjs are being included as `<script>` tags in the html page in the browser.

If it turns out that isn't the problem, you can assign a controller to a view using the **ng-controller** directive. From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

```
<ANY
  ng-controller="expression">
...
</ANY>
```

If you're using the [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) to implement routing, you assign the controller in your route's definition, like so:

```
$routeProvider
   .when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: 'BookController'
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The view-controller connection is probably working because if I remove the "parameter." from the ng-model of each field, I can access the individual fields like this - $scope.parameterName.